# I need split vector in diffrent column each factor R

Tags: r, split

My data have different length factors like this.

```
variable <- c("A,B,C","A,B","A,C","B,C")
```

I had used `strsplit` and other similar function, but I can't solve my problem

I need to get a data.frame like this

```
   A   B  C
1  A   B  C
2  A   B  NA
3  A   NA C
4  NA  B  C
```

**Thanks**

Comment: sorry for my english, it is not very good :/

Comment: Shouldn't the last row be `NA    "B"    "C" `?

Comment: Yes oskar, you're right, i gonna edit this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could split the data on comma, create dataframe and assign names based on variable name. We can then bind rows by column names using `bind_rows` from `dplyr`.

```
dplyr::bind_rows(sapply(strsplit(variable, ","), function(x) 
                setNames(as.data.frame(t(x)), x)))

#     A    B    C
#1    A    B    C
#2    A    B <NA>
#3    A <NA>    C
#4 <NA>    B    C
```

Comment: It's a great answer. Thanks Ronak :D

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(strsplit(variable, ","),
      function(x) setNames(as.list(x), x)), fill = TRUE)
```